# Fabricate entities with multiple IDENTITY PKs?

Tags: sql, primary-key, entity, identity-column

Disclosure: I'm a 'natural key' advocate myself and averse to the IDENTITY PK approach. But I do have a 'live and let live' approach to lifestyle choices, so no religious arguments here please :)

I have inherited a table where the only key is the IDENTITY PK column; let's call it ID. There are a many tables that reference ID. The intended process of creating a new entity seems to be:

1. INSERT INTO the table.
2. Use scope_identity to grab the
   auto-generated ID.
3. Use the auto-generated ID to INSERT
   into related tables.

In fact, there is a helper stored proc to create an entity and return the ID. However, I have a couple of issues:

I need to go further than the helper stored proc and create rows in related tables which themselves have IDENTITY PKs, so for each entity I need to grab several auto-generated values along the way.
I need to fabricate several hundred entities and the helper procs are coded to handle one entity at a time.

What is the best way to bulk fabricate entities using the 'IDENTITY PK' design?

When using my own 'natural key' designs, I can generate the key values in advance, therefore it's simply a case of loading some scratch tables and INSERTing into the tables in the order expected by the foreign keys. Therefore, I'm tempted to find a sequence of high value INTEGER values (to match the type of the IDENTIY columns) which I know isn't being used now and hope that they won't be being used when the time comes to do the INSERT. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking specifically about MS SQL Server?

It is unfortunate that IDENTITY columns disallow explicit inserts by default. In other DBMSs, being auto-increment wouldn't stop you from inserting an explicit value into that column, which would make it easy to choose the keys in advance. Unfortunately on SQL Server you have the inconvenience of [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) to worry about.

> there is a helper stored proc to create an entity and return the ID.

It seems a little over-the-top to me to use an sproc for that, since it's generally as simple as selecting the [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx). Quite often you can avoid the explicit select by writing each insert such that it can use the last insert's SCOPE_IDENTITY() directly.

> find a sequence of high value INTEGER values which I know isn't being used now and hope that they won't be being used [...] Is this a good idea?

They don't necessarily have to be very high values; in fact if you did that often you'd be making many huge gaps in the IDENTITY values, which is generally better avoided. You could even use the `MAX(column)+1` values as long as you either caught the error where someone else used those values in between times, or, better, do a select-max then insert in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, SQL Server. I can't use SCOPE_IDENTITY() because I want to builk insert (lets say 100 rows) rather than one at a time. So the select-max then insert could work but how to find out the values that were created for my 100 records and nobody else's?

Comment: 100 rows isn't a lot, you could easily have a script loop through them one-by-one and it still wouldn't take a noticeable amount of time. Or, select-max to get the first free row and insert rows with identity values in a contiguous block following that: though you would have in that case to INSERT the 100 rows in the first table in one go using IDENTITY_INSERT on it, *then* insert the 100 corresponding rows on the next text with IDENTITY_INSERT, since it can only be set on one table at once.